# SqlModel datetime field is throwing error upon execution

Tags: python, datetime, fastapi, sqlmodel

I am using SQLModel in python 3.8

When I add my datetime field `created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=utcnow(), nullable=False)`

I get this
**Error**

```
File "./app/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Post(SQLModel, table=True):
  File "/Users/markwardell/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlmodel/main.py", line 277, in __new__
    new_cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_used, **config_kwargs)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 204, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 488, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 419, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 539, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 801, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 718, in find_validators
RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of <module 'datetime' from '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/datetime.py'> (type: module)
```

If I do not the add the `created_at` the table is created in PostgresSql as expected.
**Code**

```
import datetime
from typing import Optional
import utcnow as utcnow
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP, text
from sqlmodel import Field, Session, SQLModel, create_engine, select
from app.database import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL

class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, index=True)


class Post(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title: str = Field(nullable=False)
    content: str = Field(nullable=False)
    published: bool = Field(default=True, nullable=False)
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=utcnow(), nullable=False)

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)


def create_db_and_tables():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    create_db_and_tables()
```

Comment: Your import should be `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: @KlausD.  that fixes it. If you like add as answer and i will follow with the answered checkmark. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was explained in a comment, but just to add it as an answer for others:

You must import datetime like this

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

The `datetime` we require in this context is a actually a class inside a module that is also called `datetime`.

Answer (score 11):

Also, note that your code should be

```
created_at: datetime.datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
```

without calling utcnow on instantiation, doing so will give every entry datetime as consulted at instantiation. Thus, `default_factory` should be the function, not the value.

Comment: `default_factory=datetime.datetime.utcnow` I think